# Wrapping output in html link

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe

Hi I have this piece of code I'm using with a ACF embed field:

```
<?php
// Load value.
$iframe = get_field('video');
// Use preg_match to find iframe src.
preg_match('/src="(.+?)"/', $iframe, $matches);
$src = $matches[1];
// Add extra parameters to src and replcae HTML.
$params = array(
'title'   => 0,
'byline'   => 0,
'portrait'   => 0,
'muted'   => 1,
'autoplay'   => 1,
'autopause'   => 1,
'controls'   => 0,
'loop'   => 1,
'background'   => 0,
);
$new_src = add_query_arg($params, $src);
$iframe = str_replace($src, $new_src, $iframe);
// Add extra attributes to iframe HTML.
$attributes = 'frameborder="0"';
$iframe = str_replace('></iframe>', ' ' . $attributes . '></iframe>', $iframe);

// Display customized HTML.
echo $iframe;
?>
```

Id like to wrap the output echo $iframe; with a link to the post below but not sure how to format it.

```
<a rel="external" href="<? the_permalink()?>">  </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you look for?

*If you are in the loop it supposed to work

```
// Display customized HTML.
echo '<a rel="external" href="'.the_permalink().'">'.$iframe.'</a>';
```